# How to push and shift value in constructor by receiving CSV data

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, csv

My goal is to display a graph of air consommation, so I want to have an array with 10 datas, and I `.push()` to each loop the new value, and I `.shift()` the first to have a live graph.

I don't find where I can do this opération. To start, I receive data from an API in CSV and I cut where I must. After receiving every datas, I associate the value with a key, but to each operation, the value is replace and I don't find how to get the older array and modify it.

This is my code :

```
import {BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, forkJoin, timer} from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class LineService{
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getData();
  }

  lineSubject = new BehaviorSubject<RcvData[]>([]);

  getData(): void {
    const lists: string[] = [
      'assets/donnee-l1.csv',
      'assets/donnee-l2.csv',
      'assets/donnee-l3.csv',
      'assets/donnee-l4.csv',
      'assets/donnee-l5.csv',
      'https://192.168.0.2/DataLogs?Path=/DataLogs/MyDataLog9.csv&Action=DOWNLOAD&E=1'
    ];
    const reqs$ = lists.map(list => this.http.get(list, {responseType: 'text'}));

    timer(0, 5000).pipe(
      switchMap(_ => forkJoin(reqs$))
    ).subscribe(listResults => {
        const parsedListResults = listResults.map(data => {
          const csvToRowArray = data.split('\n');
          const lastRow = csvToRowArray[csvToRowArray.length - 2];
          const row = lastRow.split(',');
          return new RcvData(
            parseInt(row[0], 10),
            row[1], row[2], parseInt(row[3], 10), row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7],
            parseInt(row[8], 10),
            parseInt(row[9], 10),
            parseInt(row[10], 10),
            parseInt(row[11], 10),
            parseFloat(row[12]),
            parseFloat(row[13]),
            parseFloat(row[14]),
            parseFloat(row[15]),
            parseFloat(row[16]),
            parseInt(row[17], 10),
          );
        });
        this.lineSubject.next(parsedListResults);
      });
  }
}

class RcvData{
  seqNo: number;
  date: string;
  utcTime: string;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  refCharge: string;
  refDecharge: string;
  quantiteEnCours: string;
  quantiteHoraireReel: number;
  quantiteHoraireTheorique: number;
  quantitePosteReel: number;
  quantitePosteTheorique: number;
  trpHeureReel: number;
  trpPosteReel: number;
  trpObjectif: number;
  consoAir: number;
  consoElec: number;
  status: number;
  graphAir: any = new Array(10).fill(0); ????

  constructor(
    seqNo: number,
    date: string,
    utcTime: string,
    id: number,
    name: string,
    refCharge: string,
    refDecharge: string,
    quantiteEnCours: string,
    quantiteHoraireReel: number,
    quantiteHoraireTheorique: number,
    quantitePosteReel: number,
    quantitePosteTheorique: number,
    trpHeureReel: number,
    trpPosteReel: number,
    trpObjectif: number,
    consoAir: number,
    consoElec: number,
    status: number,
    graphAir: undefined ????? )
  {
    this.seqNo = seqNo;
    this.date = date.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/"/g, '');
    this.utcTime = utcTime.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/"/g, '');
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name.replace(/"/g, '');
    this.refCharge = refCharge.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/"/g, '');
    this.refDecharge = refDecharge.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/"/g, '');
    this.quantiteEnCours = quantiteEnCours.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/"/g, '');
    this.quantiteHoraireReel = quantiteHoraireReel;
    this.quantiteHoraireTheorique = quantiteHoraireTheorique;
    this.quantitePosteReel = quantitePosteReel;
    this.quantitePosteTheorique = quantitePosteTheorique;
    this.trpHeureReel = trpHeureReel;
    this.trpPosteReel = trpPosteReel;
    this.trpObjectif = trpObjectif;
    this.consoAir = consoAir;
    this.consoElec = consoElec;
    this.status = status;
    this.graphAir = graphAir ????;
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the solution !

I declare an object before the injection, and I associate the good array to the lineSubject.

```
import {BehaviorSubject, combineLatest, forkJoin, timer} from 'rxjs';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class LineService{
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.getData();
  }

  public graphAir$ = [  new Array(10).fill(0),
                        new Array(10).fill(0),
                        new Array(10).fill(0),
                        new Array(10).fill(0),
                        new Array(10).fill(0),
                        new Array(10).fill(0) ];
  public graphElec$ = [  new Array(10).fill(0),
                        new Array(10).fill(0),
                        new Array(10).fill(0),
                        new Array(10).fill(0),
                        new Array(10).fill(0),
                        new Array(10).fill(0) ];
  lineSubject = new BehaviorSubject<RcvData[]>([]);

  getData(): void {
    const lists: string[] = [
      'assets/donnee-l1.csv',
      'assets/donnee-l2.csv',
      'assets/donnee-l3.csv',
      'assets/donnee-l4.csv',
      'assets/donnee-l5.csv',
      'https://192.168.0.2/DataLogs?Path=/DataLogs/MyDataLog9.csv&Action=DOWNLOAD&E=1'
    ];
    const reqs$ = lists.map(list => this.http.get(list, {responseType: 'text'}));

    timer(0, 5000).pipe(
      switchMap(_ => forkJoin(reqs$))
    ).subscribe(listResults => {
        const parsedListResults = listResults.map(data => {
          const csvToRowArray = data.split('\n');
          const lastRow = csvToRowArray[csvToRowArray.length - 2];
          const row = lastRow.split(',');
          return new RcvData(
            parseInt(row[0], 10),
            row[1], row[2], parseInt(row[3], 10), row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7],
            parseInt(row[8], 10),
            parseInt(row[9], 10),
            parseInt(row[10], 10),
            parseInt(row[11], 10),
            parseFloat(row[12]),
            parseFloat(row[13]),
            parseFloat(row[14]),
            parseFloat(row[15]),
            parseFloat(row[16]),
            parseInt(row[17], 10),
            this.graphAir$[parseInt(row[3], 10) - 1],
            this.graphElec$[parseInt(row[3], 10) - 1]
          );
        });

        for(const module of parsedListResults){
          this.graphAir$[module.id - 1].shift();
          this.graphAir$[module.id - 1].push(module.consoAir);
          this.graphElec$[module.id - 1].shift();
          this.graphElec$[module.id - 1].push(module.consoElec);
        }

        this.lineSubject.next(parsedListResults);

        console.log(parsedListResults);

      });
  }
}

class RcvData{
  seqNo: number;
  date: string;
  utcTime: string;
  id: number;
  name: string;
  refCharge: string;
  refDecharge: string;
  quantiteEnCours: string;
  quantiteHoraireReel: number;
  quantiteHoraireTheorique: number;
  quantitePosteReel: number;
  quantitePosteTheorique: number;
  trpHeureReel: number;
  trpPosteReel: number;
  trpObjectif: number;
  consoAir: number;
  consoElec: number;
  status: number;
  graphAir: object;
  graphElec: object;

  constructor(
    seqNo: number,
    date: string,
    utcTime: string,
    id: number,
    name: string,
    refCharge: string,
    refDecharge: string,
    quantiteEnCours: string,
    quantiteHoraireReel: number,
    quantiteHoraireTheorique: number,
    quantitePosteReel: number,
    quantitePosteTheorique: number,
    trpHeureReel: number,
    trpPosteReel: number,
    trpObjectif: number,
    consoAir: number,
    consoElec: number,
    status: number,
    graphAir: object,
    graphElec: object)
  {
    this.seqNo = seqNo;
    this.date = date.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/"/g, '');
    this.utcTime = utcTime.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/"/g, '');
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name.replace(/"/g, '');
    this.refCharge = refCharge.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/"/g, '');
    this.refDecharge = refDecharge.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/"/g, '');
    this.quantiteEnCours = quantiteEnCours.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/"/g, '');
    this.quantiteHoraireReel = quantiteHoraireReel;
    this.quantiteHoraireTheorique = quantiteHoraireTheorique;
    this.quantitePosteReel = quantitePosteReel;
    this.quantitePosteTheorique = quantitePosteTheorique;
    this.trpHeureReel = trpHeureReel;
    this.trpPosteReel = trpPosteReel;
    this.trpObjectif = trpObjectif;
    this.consoAir = consoAir;
    this.consoElec = consoElec;
    this.status = status;
    this.graphAir = graphAir;
    this.graphElec = graphElec;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `BehaviorSubject`, you could use it's `value` getter to get the current value in the observable and use the spread operator to append values to existing array.

Try the following

```js
getData(): void {
  const lists: string[] = [
    // removed for brevity
  ];
  const reqs$ = lists.map(list => this.http.get(list, {responseType: 'text'}));

  timer(0, 5000).pipe(
    switchMap(_ => forkJoin(reqs$))
  ).subscribe(listResults => {
    const parsedListResults = listResults.map(data => {
      // removed for brevity
    });

    this.lineSubject.next([...this.lineSubject.value, ...parsedListResults]);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I just want to add the new "consoAir" to the "graphAir" variable, not the other value. Have you an idea ?
At the beginning, I have :
ConsoGraph = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], and after, only this variable is save to have :
ConsoGraph = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,new consoAir value]

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your answer but I have a problem with that. The website will never refresh so I would not like to have infinite variable ...

It's not possible with other methode in the constructor or elsewhere ?